# find_by returning only first value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to retrieve all names of employees within a particular department.

Here is what I have done:

```
Employee.find_by(department:'IT').name
```

But it is returning only first value.

This is what I get in console:

```
SELECT  "employee".* FROM "employee" WHERE "employee"."department" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["department","IT"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Why LIMIT 1 is applied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what [`find_by(..)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L81) does; it's a shortcut for `where(..).first`.

If you want all the records, you need to use `where`.

```
Employee.where(department:'IT').map(&:name)
```

Comment: If `name` is an Employee's attribute, use pluck over map.

Comment: name is Employee's attribute

Comment: @SebastianPalma yeah, I was torn on that. I just didn't want to confuse things by doing something that doesn't really return all the model instances.

Comment: Second example should be `Employee where(department: 'IT').pluck(:name)` (just for reference...already discussed in the comments)

Comment: @matthewd then `select(:name)` would also work. This will return model instances with only 1 attribute (`name`). However that is a lot of overhead for no real gain